# How to update an arraylist using mongotemplate?

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc, mongotemplate

I am using mongoTemplate for inserting, deleting and updating the data in my program. I just want to update an arraylist values in a pojo class using this mongotemplate.

This is my parent Class - Search

```
    @Document(collection = "search_details")
    public class Search {

        @Id
        private String id;
        private String searchkey;
        private ArrayList<Lead> leads;
private String status;

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public ArrayList<Lead> getLeads() {
            return leads;
        }

        public void setLeads(ArrayList<Lead> leads) {
            this.leads = leads;
        }

    }
```

Class Lead

public class Lead {

```
private String id;
private String title;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
```

}

Update code :

```
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("searchkey").is("test").andOperator(Criteria.where("status").is("active").andOperator(criteria.elemMatch(Criteria.where("leads.id").is("101"))));
    Update update = new Update();
    update.set("leads.title", "new title");
Search searchResult = mongoTemplate.findAndModify(query, update, Search.class);
```

I have checked the database for the result. Values are present in the database for this same query. But using mongotemplate i couldn't get the updated result from the database. please help me to find the correct answer for updating using mongotemplate. I am getting the mongosocket exception for updating the scenario.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.MongoSocketException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1324)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:58)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:1918)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindOneInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1748)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFindOne(MongoTemplate.java:1562)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findOne(MongoTemplate.java:497)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findOne(MongoTemplate.java:492)
    at com.datanovation.Kuer8tor3WebServices.DAOImpls.LeadDAOImpl.editLead(LeadDAOImpl.java:127)
    at com.datanovation.Kuer8tor3WebServices.ServiceImpls.LeadServiceImpl.editLead(LeadServiceImpl.java:43)
    at com.datanovation.Kuer8tor3WebServices.Controllers.LeadController.editLead(LeadController.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Code. Data Structure. Class definition possibly. All missing from your post. If you want to be loved then read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

You should define your arraylist field as @ElementCollection . Maybe [this](http://en.kodcu.com/2013/08/nosql-with-jpa/) example can help you.